# disable an input if another input is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have three sections in a form, the first one contains one input and the second contains three inputs and the third contains a checkbox. How to

1. disable the two sections if checkbox is checked
2. disable the checkbox and a section if I tapped a text in the other section
3. enable the three sections if all of them are empty

I must have only one active section everytime.

What I did is not the solution because there is a problem in the second section. if only one input is empty in this section all the other inputs are enabled. any one can help me please.
Thanks and sorry about my english

```js
document.getElementById("client").onblur = function () {
            if (this.value.length > 0) {
                document.getElementById("FirstName").disabled=true;
                document.getElementById("LastName").disabled=true;
                document.getElementById("Email").disabled=true;
                document.getElementById("standard").disabled=true;
            }else {
                document.getElementById("FirstName").disabled=false;
                document.getElementById("LastName").disabled=false;
                document.getElementById("Email").disabled=false;
                document.getElementById("standard").disabled=false;
            }
        }
        
        document.getElementById("FirstName").onblur = function () {
            if (this.value.length > 0) {
                document.getElementById("client").disabled=true; 
                document.getElementById("standard").disabled=true;
            }else {
                document.getElementById("client").disabled = false;
                document.getElementById("standard").disabled = false;
            }
        }
        document.getElementById("LastName").onblur = function () {
            if (this.value.length > 0) {
                document.getElementById("client").disabled=true; 
                document.getElementById("standard").disabled=true;
            }else {
                document.getElementById("client").disabled = false;
                document.getElementById("standard").disabled = false;
            }
        }
        document.getElementById("Email").onblur = function () {
            if (this.value.length > 0) {
                document.getElementById("client").disabled=true; 
                document.getElementById("standard").disabled=true;
            }else {
                document.getElementById("client").disabled = false;
                document.getElementById("standard").disabled = false;
            }
        }
        document.getElementById("standard").onblur = function () {
            if (this.checked) {
                document.getElementById("client").disabled=true; 
                document.getElementById("FirstName").disabled=true;
                document.getElementById("LastName").disabled=true;
                document.getElementById("Email").disabled=true;
            }else {
                document.getElementById("client").disabled=false; 
                document.getElementById("FirstName").disabled=false;
                document.getElementById("LastName").disabled=false;
                document.getElementById("Email").disabled=false;
            }
        }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-md-4">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="form-group col-md-12">
    <label>Search Client</label>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
   <div class="form-group col-md-12">
    <div class="input-group custom-search-form margin-bottom">
     <input id="client" name="client" type="text" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Search...">
     <span class="input-group-btn">
      <button class="btn btn-default btn-sm" type="button">
       <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
      </button>
     </span>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="col-md-8">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="form-group col-md-12">
    <label>New Client</label>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
   <div class="form-group col-md-4">
    <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" id="FirstName" placeholder="First Name">
   </div>
   <div class="form-group col-md-4">
    <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" id="LastName" placeholder="Last Name">
   </div>
   <div class="form-group col-md-4">
    <input type="email" class="form-control input-sm" id="Email" placeholder="Email">
    
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>

<div class="checkbox margin-bottom">
 <label>
  <input id="standard" type="checkbox" value="">Standard
 </label>
</div>
```

Comment: Try to implement the `onclick()` event it is pretty mutch the same as the `onblur()` you have used.

Comment: It doesn't work, I have to click twice every time to disable or enable.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you may want try the focus listener instead of the on Blur listener.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/focus

The second element seems to work when I entered in values for all of the fields. It looks like it's checking the length of what was entered.

Comment: Please provide some other reference than w3schools. Compared to MDN or even MSDN, w3schools' information tends to be inaccurate or suggest outdated patterns.